# Why is my List total not computing correctly? C#

Tags: c#

I am supposed to get values entered into a text box, then display the total of the entered values, the average of the values, and the count of how many values have been entered.

So far I have coded:

```
List<int> intScoreList = new List<int>(20);
decimal decScoreAverage = 0m;
decimal decScoreTotal = 0m;

private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int intScore = Convert.ToInt32(txtScore.Text);
    int intScoreCount = 0;
    intScoreList.Add(intScore);
    for (int i = 0; i < intScoreList.Count; i++)
    {
        intScoreList[0] = intScore;
        decScoreTotal += intScoreList[i];
        intScoreCount++; //correct
        decScoreAverage = decScoreTotal / intScoreCount; //correct
    }
```

When I enter test values of 30 then 40, the total gives me 110 (30 + 40 * 2) rather than 70 (30 + 40). Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Use Linq aggregations rather than a `for` loop.

Comment: It's not at all clear why you're overwriting `intScoreList[0]` with `intScore` at all... why are you doing that? And why are you computing the average *in the loop*? And why are you keeping a separate count when you have `intScoreList.Count`? Why not just use `average = ((decimal) intScoreList.Sum()) / intScoreList.Count`

Comment: What platform?  ASP.NET, WinForms, etc?  It sounds like the button click handler may be called twice - I've seen this happen in ASP.NET.

Comment: You're overwriting whatever's in `intScoreList[0]` with `intScore`, so that's probably what's screwing up your math.

Comment: also the loop if you enter `30` for the text only enters the for loop once then jumps out.. like I said I would highly suggest that you use the free tools that are available to you `Debbuger` is what you need to learn how to use.. this code you posted logically is totally `Flawed`

Comment: Any plans to accept an answer?

Answer (score 4):

Use `Linq`.  On the add button click event simply add the parsed value.  Then display the Avg, and Count.

```
    List<decimal> scoreList = new List<decimal>();
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimalnum;
        if (decimal.TryParse(txtScore.Text, out num))
        {
            scoreList.Add(num);
        }

        // Assign to count label Text property = scoreList.Count;
        // Assign to average label Text property = scoreList.Average();
    }
```

Now imagine the ability to reset all the user's input:

```
    private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        scoreList.Clear();
    }
```

Utilizing the list instance you can easily add number's as entered and correctly parsed from the user.  The [Average](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.average(v=vs.110).aspx) `Linq` extension method will do all the math for you, no need to do it yourself.

Comment: .Average() is LINQ, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.average(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: those are extension methods

Comment: @MethodMan, yes -- those are extension methods.  Did you notice the namespace they are in?  It is System.Linq.

Comment: I am aware of that. I was expecting to see the `IEnumerable` usage / explanation no problem

Answer (score 1):

To the commenters' (justified) point below, here's some more explanation.

You're total isn't computing correctly mainly because you are changing the first item of your recorded values: `intScoreList[0] = intScore;`. By altering it, you are interfering with the sum.

A much clean operation consists of adding your new data to the array and recomputing the sum.

```
List<int> intScoreList = new List<int>(20);      
decimal decScoreAverage = 0m;
decimal decScoreTotal = 0m;

private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int intScore = Convert.ToInt32(txtScore.Text);
    int intScoreCount = 0;
    intScoreList.Add(intScore);

    decScoreTotal = 0;
    foreach(int i in intScoreList) {
        decScoreTotal += i;
    }

    decScoreAverage = decScoreTotal / intScoreList.Count;
    intScoreCount = inScoreList.Count;
}
```

Note that this isn't necessarily the most efficient implementation since as the number of values increase, the `foreach` loop will get more and more expensive. A better approach is to keep track of the current total and average and adjust them with the new value (which you can still add to the list for other purposes if you need).

The average is computed this way:

```
New_average = old_average * (count-1)/count + new_value /count
```

And here's the new code:

```
List<int> intScoreList = new List<int>(20);      
decimal decScoreAverage = 0m;
decimal decScoreTotal = 0m;

private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int intScore = Convert.ToInt32(txtScore.Text);
    int intScoreCount = 0;
    intScoreList.Add(intScore);

    intScoreCount = inScoreList.Count;
    decScoreTotal += intScore;        
    decScoreAverage = decScoreAverage * (intScoreCount- 1)/intScoreCount + intScore/intScoreCount;

}
```

Comment: You should add a remark as to what changed and why.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't consider a for each loop. I guess all you're really needing to put through the loop is all the values to get the total, and the rest can be done outside. Thank you!

Comment: @Shelby115 The code speaks for itself here. It's simply a slight variation of the Ops code, which he apparently didn't have a problem understand. Quite happy on the downvote trigger it seems...

Comment: @mprivat I agree with trooper 100%. I didn't downvote you as I prefer to give a person a chance to correct the issue before I do so. That code speaks as much for itself as a toddler learning to talk. It may produce sounds that mean something, but it's going to take a while to figure out what they mean. That being said, it's understandably so since it's mostly the OP's code but it doesn't change my feelings towards the lack of an explanation.

Comment: @Shelby115 I agree with you both. I aimed to get the OP out of the mud quickly, but it's best to consider all readers.

Answer (score 0):

Since the loop adds up all the items,
dont' you want

```
decScoreTotal = 0
```

before your for loop?