# Working with arrays, think I'm not using for loop correctly

Tags: c#, arrays

I've only been working with Arrays for a short while, and Im finding them much harder than working with Lists. For an assignment I have written a form with takes an input from a textbox and outputs a count,average, and total. The code is as follows:

```
int [] intScoreTotalArray = new int[20];      
decimal decScoreAverage = 0m;
decimal decScoreTotal = 0m;
decimal decScoreCount = 0m;

private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    intScoreTotalArray[0] = Convert.ToInt32(txtScore.Text);
    for(int i = 0; i < intScoreTotalArray.Length; i++)
    {
        decScoreTotal += intScoreTotalArray[i];
    }

    decScoreCount++;  
    decScoreAverage = decScoreTotal / decScoreCount;
```

But I also need to display it in a message box in a stong, and it only gives me the last value. My theory is that the problem lies in both boxes of code, or in the intial for loop.

```
private void btnDisplayScores_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal decScore = Convert.ToDecimal(txtScore.Text);

    string strScoreTotal = " ";
    for (int i = 0; i < intScoreTotalArray[i]; i++)
    {
        strScoreTotal += decScore.ToString() + "\n";
    }
    Array.Sort(intScoreTotalArray);
    MessageBox.Show(strScoreTotal + "\n","Score Array");
```

Advice?

Comment: decScoreCount++;   is outside your loop, so it will only get incremented once.

Comment: "*need to display it*" What is **it**? The count/average/total or the items in the array?

Comment: How are they much harder to work with?

Comment: You only ever set the first item with `intScoreTotalArray[0] = Convert.ToInt32(txtScore.Text);`  Try `intScoreTotalArray[decScoreCount] = int.Parse(txtScore.Text);`

Comment: why are you posting the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33678893/why-is-my-list-total-not-computing-correctly-c-sharp also not sure why you can't use a `List<T>`

Comment: @MethodMan: Not exactly the same, that one's a list, this is an array.

Comment: Where are the other numbers coming from? It looks like you have just the one textbox with a value being used here,

Comment: no it's the same the OP just doesn't understand `List<T>` is what I am gathering from the same post.. not to mention `Array.Sort` come on List<T>Sort() method would be a much better option also `Stop posting partial code` please `Ask your Instructor` to explain `Arrays` they are just as easy to understand as List<T> here is a Tutorail you should utilize http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/Lesson02

Comment: you need to learn to use the debugger also step through the code and you will see where all of your logical mishaps are occurring

Comment: also initialize your strings using `string.Empty` not `string strScoreTotal = " "` because the with the space in `" "` that's not the same as `""`

Comment: @MethodMan: The assignment is two identical problems, one must be accomplished using arrays and another though lists. My main issue is loop logic and methods. Apologies.

Comment: in all due respect you are taking a simple problem and making  your @sugarpeas issue more complex than it needs to be I would personally suggest do a google search on some basic C# tutorials focusing on `Arrays, Loops, and List<T> Generics` expecting someone to give you an answer and or solution without understanding the in's and out's is quite counter productive

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using an array to determine the count, average and total of a list of numbers? They aren't the best structure for a dynamic list of items as you have to declare an array's size when you initialize it. You SHOULD be using a list for this task.

As to why your code isn't behaving:

```
intScoreTotalArray[0] = Convert.ToInt32(txtScore.Text);
```

You are only assigning the first item in the array here.

It looks like you are using decScoreCount to keep track of the number of items in your array. I think you want to do this:

```
intScoreTotalArray[(int) decScoreCount] = Convert.ToInt32(txtScore.Text);
```